# Uncaught exception in FutureBuilder, is it normal?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, future

If I throw an exception in a Future, and use such future in a FutureBuilder, the debugger warns me about it being "uncaught". Is this by design or am I using FutureBuilders wrong?

My scenario is a typical one: show a loading spinner while data is retrieved from an HTTP API. I do so through the following (simplified) code:

```
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  Future<String> getSomeText() async {
    // Just throw an exception here to simulate a network error
    throw Exception("Network error");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder(
    future: getSomeText(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text("Got an error");
        return Text(snapshot.data);
      }
      else
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  );
}
```

When I draw this widget, the `Network error` exception is thrown and my debugger (I use VSCode with the official Flutter plugin) halts execution and shows it to me. If I then chose to continue execution, the app behaves as expected.

Reading around a bit, I thought that happens because `getSomeText()` gets called and completes BEFORE the builder is even created, and the builder's exception handlers do not have time to register with the future. However, using `Future.delay()` to introduce a delay results in exactly the same behavior.

I also tried to execute such code in one of Flutter's documentation code boxes, and there it apparently works without throwing exceptions. Is it simply ignoring it as it is thrown into a Future?

I wonder if such exception should be caught (as I expect) or not? Is leaving it uncaught in this scenario a Flutter design choice?

Comment: how does the debugger warns you? im asking sinc the `Future` you pass to `FutureBuilder` is caught here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fb57da5f94/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L634-L638

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The debugger clearly shows that the exception is thrown BEFORE the builder even gets executed, and stops the code flow right at the `throw` line. If I opt for continuing the execution step-by-step after that point, I can see that the builder is indeed executed immediately afterwards.
Looking at the link you provided, it seems to make sense. `getSomeText()` is executed, and then its return value (a Future) passed to the `FutureBuilder` constructor, which only then subscribes an error handler. But by then, the Future has likely already thrown the Exception.

Comment: i run the following code and there is no "uncaught" exception shown by the debugger `class Foo1 extends StatelessWidget {
Foo1() {
dbg('=========== ctor');
}

Future<void> foo() async {
dbg('=========== foo');
throw 'foo';
}

dbg(msg) {
print(msg);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
dbg('=========== build');
return FutureBuilder(
future: foo(),
builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
return Text('snapshot: $snapshot');
}
);
}
}` - flutter 3.0.0, dart 2.17.0

Comment: I replaced my widget with yours, and the exception `foo` DOES occur. Here's my `flutter --version` output:
`Flutter 3.0.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fb57da5f94 (3 weeks ago) • 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700
Engine • revision caaafc5604
Tools • Dart 2.17.1 • DevTools 2.12.2 `
I'm using VSCode (1.67.2) with Flutter (3.42.0) and Dart (3.42.1) extensions.

Comment: if it still bothers you, replace `throw 'foo'` with `return Future.error('foo')`

Comment: After digging into the FutureBuilder class implementation and observing general exception handling in my app, I think that VSCode's debugger halts execution whenever an exception is thrown, regardless of whether it will be caught or not. Will update if I ever find out why that is the case.

Comment: good luck then :-)